# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (4x^2-x)^{1/2}+2x$

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (4x^2-x)^{1/2}+2x$$

**My try:-**
$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (4x^2-x)^{1/2}+2x$
= $\lim_{x\to -\infty} (4x^2-x-4x^2)/ ((4x^2-x)^{1/2}-2x)$=-$\infty$

I know this is incorrect as I have seen its graph which tends to 0.25.
This means I have done a mistake. But I am unable to find it out.

Comment: in this case I always suggest to change variable in order to deal with $lim \to \infty$ and avoid mistakes with the signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-1/x}}=\frac{1}{4}$$
$\textbf{Addendum:}$ The last step in the limit follows from the following 
$$2-\sqrt{4x^2-x}/x=2+\sqrt{4x^2-x}/|x|=2+\sqrt{4x^2/x^2-x/x^2}=2+\sqrt{4-1/x}$$
whenever $x<0$.

Comment: that's way to solve is completely unclear, how is the justification of the last step? I suggest the OP to avoid this method since it can easily leads to a mistake with some sign, as it was for you in the first version.

Comment: @gimusi Since $2-\sqrt{4x^2-x}/x=2+\sqrt{4x^2-x}/|x|=2+\sqrt{4x^2/x^2-x/x^2}$ and so on. (since $x<0$)

Comment: you should add the full step in your derivation in order to don't give the erroneous idea that the step is straightforward since indeed it needs to be handled very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x<0$
$$(4x^2-x)^{1/2}=-2x\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)^{1/2}=-2x\left(1-\frac1{8x}+O(|x|^{-2})\right)
$$
etc.

Comment: sir, i have understood your approach but why i am unable to solve by rationalizing numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Let $-\dfrac1x=h\implies h\to0^+, h>0$

$$4x^2-x=\dfrac{4-h}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{4x^2-x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-h}}h$$

as $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|=+h$ as $h>0$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{4-h}-2}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{4-h-4}h\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}(\sqrt{4-h}+2)}=?$$

Comment: sir, i have understood your approach but why i am unable to solve by rationalizing numerator.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=-x\to \infty$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x=\lim_{y\to \infty} \sqrt{4y^2+y}-2y$$

and

$$\sqrt{4y^2+y}-2y=\left(\sqrt{4y^2+y}-2y\right)\frac{\sqrt{4y^2+y}+2y}{\sqrt{4y^2+y}+2y}=\frac{4y^2+y-4y^2}{\sqrt{4y^2+y}+2y}\to \frac14$$

Answer (score 1):

Your method will also work:
$$\begin{align} &\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4x^2-x}-2x}=\\
&\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x}{-x\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{x}}-2x}=\\
&\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{x}}+2}=\\
&\frac14.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(4x^2-x-4x^2)/(4x^2-x)^{1/2}=-(4x^2-x)^{1/2}/(4x-1)$, not $(4x^2-x)^{1/2}$.

Hint. Substitute $t=-x$, and multiply $\frac{(4t^2+t)^{1/2}+2t}{(4t^2+t)^{1/2}+2t}$.

Comment: I have not used this in my trail $(4x^2-x-4x^2)/(4x^2-x)^{1/2}=$(4x^2-x)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read it wrong.